# Legitimate reason to override global options in R package?

Tags: r, r-package

I was just randomly exploring a relatively new and small R package on GitHub, and literally the very first thing I see is

`options(scipen = 999)`

Which sets off alarm bells for me. They do this multiple times, including

`options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

The reason it bothers me is because it can cause unexpected and difficult to debug behavior for users, especially for a common function like read.csv() where some people may be depending on character strings defaulting to factors

```
> dat = read.csv("a.csv")
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2
 $ b: num  NA 3.5
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "Hello","my": 1 2
> chg_saf = function() {
+   options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
+ }
> chg_saf()
> dat = read.csv("a.csv")
> str(dat)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2
 $ b: num  NA 3.5
 $ c: chr  "Hello" "my"
```

Maybe it wouldn't bother me so much if they at least attempted to restore the default state at the end of their functions, but even that would bother me because a premature exit of the function due to an error would prevent the state from being restored (I've actually encountered a package that has this issue with setwd...).

Now, I plan to submit an issue to their GitHub issue tracker politely asking them not to do this. But before I do, it has piqued my curiosity; **are there valid situations where it would be appropriate to override R's global options in an R package unbeknownst to the user?**

Comment: There are no valid situations in my opinion... But this is opinion based... It is a well backed up opinion as you won't get a package on CRAN if it alters the global environment. [see the policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html)

Comment: `on.exit()` would help with the situation described in your second-to-last-paragraph.